# Filtering nested lists with nullable property

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have the following class structures

```
public class EmailActivity {
    public IEnumerable<MemberActivity> Activity { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

public class MemberActivity {
    public EmailAction? Action { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public enum EmailAction {
    None = 0,
    Open = 1,
    Click = 2,
    Bounce = 3
}
```

I wish to filter a list of `EmailActivity` objects based on the presence of a `MemberActivity` with a non-null `EmailAction` matching a provided list of `EmailAction` matches. I want to return just the EmailAddress property as a `List<string>`.

This is as far as I've got

```
List<EmailAction> activityTypes; // [ EmailAction.Open, EmailAction.Bounce ]

List<string> activityEmailAddresses =
    emailActivity.Where(
        member => member.Activity.Where(
            activity => activityTypes.Contains(activity.Action)
        )
    )
    .Select(member => member.EmailAddress)
    .ToList();
```

However I get an error message "CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'EmailAction?' to 'EmailAction'"

If then modify `activityTypes` to allow null values `List<EmailAction?>` I get the following "CS1662 Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type".

The issue is the nested `.Where` it's returning a list, but the parent `.Where` requires a bool result. How would I tackle this problem?

I realise I could do with with nested loops however I'm trying to brush up my C# skills!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `List.Contains` is not ideal in terms of performance, `HashSet` is a better option, also if you want to select the email address as soon as it contains one of the searched actions, you can use `Any`:

```
var activityTypes = new HashSet<EmailAction>() { EmailAction.Open, EmailAction.Bounce };

List<string> activityEmailAddresses =
    emailActivity.Where(
        member => member.Activity.Any(
            activity => activity.Action.HasValue && 
                        activityTypes.Contains(activity.Action.Value)
    )
)
.Select(activity => activity.EmailAddress)
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `All` or `Any` depends if you want each or at least one match...

```
HashSet<EmailAction> activityTypes = new HashSet<EmailAction> { EmailAction.None };

var emailActivity = new List<EmailActivity>
{
    new EmailActivity { Activity = new List<MemberActivity>{ new MemberActivity { Action = EmailAction.None } }, EmailAddress = "a" },
    new EmailActivity { Activity = new List<MemberActivity>{ new MemberActivity { Action = EmailAction.Click } }, EmailAddress = "b" }
};

// Example with Any but All can be used as well
var activityEmailAddresses = emailActivity
    .Where(x => x.Activity.Any(_ => _.Action.HasValue && activityTypes.Contains(_.Action.Value)))
    .Select(x => x.EmailAddress)
    .ToArray();
// Result is [ "a" ]
```